# Does core-3 have a way to define an instance of type double in xaml similar to the use of mscorlib in .net?

Tags: wpf, xaml, asp.net-core, double

I am migrating our WPF code to Core 3 and have not found a solution to the problem of defining a double in xaml.

I have searched using various terms but get nothing but the old method of using mscorlib which is not available in core 3.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Instead of referencing mscorlib you just need to reference System.Runtime, like so:

```
<...
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Runtime"
...>
```